# Global Variable getting nulled | VUE JS | Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I need help in checking the issue with the Global variable where it is getting null on assigning it to a local variable.

For Example

A = array('a','b');
let B = A

I am using the B variable but the Global Variable A is getting Empty.

I am attaching the VUE JS script for reference.

Please check if anyone can help. It will be really appreciated.

```
createBoxes(spec = '') {
        let speci = []
        if (spec == '') {
            speci = this.tabs_specifications
        } else {
            speci = spec
        }
        let box = []
        for (var j = 1; j <= this.tab_cut; j++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < speci.length; i++) {
                if (speci[i].tab_position == j) {
                    box.push(speci[i]);
                    speci.splice(i, 1)
                    this.total_boxes = this.total_boxes+1
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        this.proof_boxes.push(box)
        let spicify = speci
        if (speci.length > 0) {
            this.createBoxes(spicify)
        } else {
            this.customize_tab.proof_boxes = this.proof_boxes
            // window.localStorage.setItem('customizeTab', JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.customize_tab));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. where is your global variable and which line your getting null.?

Comment: @KamleshPaul "this.tabs_specifications" this is gloabal variable

as soon as I use "speci.splice(i, 1)" my global variable going to empty

Comment: `speci` references `this.tabs_specifications` and `splice` mutates the array it is called on, so this behavior is exactly as expected.

Comment: @KamleshPaul So what is the solution for this that my global variable don't be empty after splice the local variable